# How to remove unneeded build artefacts after cabal install

Tags: haskell, pandoc, cabal-install

I am installing a few packages (`pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc`) using `cabal install` in order to build more recent binaries of these packages than are currently available through my package manager (debian's `apt-get`).  This works great but installs gads of additional packages that are presumably needed for the build process, taking up much more space* than when I install the debian binaries alone.

How can I go about removing these artefacts needed to build the `pandoc` and `pandoc-citeproc` binaries once the binaries are complete, without removing necessary files? (e.g. is it sufficient to keep `cabal/bin` and remove everything else?  Would the `cabal-debian` package be of any use here? Or is there a built-in method in cabal for this?)

---

* Yes, I care about disk space. In this case because I am building this as a docker image which I would prefer be no larger than necessary, though in principle this question is more general than the docker use case.

Comment: Would you consider making a cabal sandbox and cabal installing everything in that sandbox then copying the executables in the .cabal-sandbox/bin/ directory to the ~/.cabal/bin/ directory. Then deleting the sandbox?

Comment: Equivalently one could use `--bindir` option on `cabal install`. But deleting everything but `bin` deletes `.cabal/shared` which causes the binaries to malfunction.  Which I knew if `shared/` and `bin/` were the only things I needed to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up following along the lines of @DiegoNolan's suggestion:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y cabal-install \
  && cabal update \
  && cabal install --bindir=/usr/local/bin --global pandoc pandoc-citeproc \
  && apt-get remove --auto-remove --purge -y cabal-install \
  && rm -rf /root/.cabal/lib /root/.cabal/packages
```

Which results in adding < 100 MB instead of 1.2 GB to the image size.  In addition to dropping `.cabal/lib` after install, found it was necessary to remove the build dependencies added by `cabal-install` with the `--auto-remove --purge` command once the installation was done.  (Since I was doing this in Docker all commands had to appear in the same AUFS layer, hence the multiple `&&`)